# jQuery Mobile AJAX doesn't load page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
echo '<script>
    function ' . $row['idname'] . 'Click(){
        $( "#flip-' . $row['idname'] . '" ).flipswitch( "disable" );
        var isOff = document.getElementById("flip-' . $row['idname'] . '").value;
        if(isOff == "off"){
            console.log("action.php?do=turn-off-' . $row["id"] . '");
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "action.php?do=turn-off-' . $row["id"] . '",
                type: "GET",
                success:function (data) {
                    $( "#flip-' . $row['idname'] . '" ).flipswitch( "enable" );
                    console.log("SUCCESS!!");
                }
            });
        }else{
            console.log("action.php?do=turn-on-' . $row["id"] . '");
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "action.php?do=turn-on-' . $row["id"] . ',
                type: "GET",
                success : function (data) {
                    $( "#flip-' . $row['idname'] . '" ).flipswitch( "enable" );
                    console.log("SUCCESS!!");
                }
            });
        }
    }
    </script><br>';
```

So my problem is that ajax doesn't even load the page that is requested.

It creates this code from the result of a MySQL query, so it's basically a JavaScript file in a PHP File. The target is an empty page that only has some functions.

The function is invoked `onChange` from this `<select>`:

```
echo '<div class="ui-field-contain" style="width: 100%;">
    <label for="flip-' . $row['idname'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</label> 
    <select onchange="' . $row['idname'] . 'Click()" name="flip-' . $row['idname'] . '" id="flip-' . $row['idname'] . '" data-role="flipswitch">
        <option value="off" selected="">Aus</option> <option value="on">An</option> 
    </select>
 </div>';
```

Comment: silly question: the function is called somewhere, right? (i'm asking since it has a *dynamic* name generate via *php*.. (Why don't you create a function which accepts your `$row['idname'` as an argument?

Comment: of course it gets called - and I didn't want to just call that function because action.php should work like an api later, by calling this page, action x will be performed.

Comment: ok, thanks (I've added the code to the question since from the comments its pretty unreadable)

Comment: Are the `console.log` you've placed in the code called?

Comment: Yes they are, I've also added a console.log call in action.php and this one doesn't get called (so obviously the page doesn't even get called)

Comment: What happens if you change your code to:
`var request = jQuery.ajax(...); 
request.always(function(data){console.log(data)});
request.fail(function(error){console.log(error)});`
You should skip the success inside the ajax call and may replace it with `request.done(...)`

Comment: Now the console shows me this: `<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: PAGE!!!!!');</script>`
(action.php outputs "PAGE!!!!!")

Answer (score 0):

This may solve the problem because it is not a nice way to just replace it with always. You might consider adding some error handling where no wrong elements are tested to be selected with the error message as a part of the id.

**Deprecated jqXHR.success()**

The issue may occur because this method is deprecated since jQuery 1.8. It has been replaced by jqXHR.done().

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "action.php?do=turn-on-' . $row["id"] . '",
    type: "GET",
    done: function (data) {
        $( "#flip-' . $row['idname'] . '" ).flipswitch( "enable" );
        console.log("SUCCESS!!");
    }
});
```

**Suggesting another way**

```
$.get("api.php", {
    do: "turn-on-' . $row["id"] . '"
}, function (data) {
    console.log(data);}
});
```